# How to use select column aliases in subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering this query:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.date, "%Y") training_year, 
COUNT(i.id) nb_trainees, 
nb_canceled_trainings, 
nb_done_trainings, 
(nb_canceled_trainings / (nb_canceled_trainings + nb_done_trainings)) cancellation_rate
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(`trainings_trainings`.`id`) nb_canceled_trainings
    FROM  `trainings_trainings`
    WHERE `trainings_trainings`.`id_status` = 5
    AND DATE_FORMAT(`trainings_trainings`.`date`, "%Y") = training_year
) nct, (
    SELECT COUNT(`trainings_trainings`.`id`) nb_done_trainings
    FROM  `trainings_trainings`
    WHERE `trainings_trainings`.`id_status` IN (6, 7)
    AND DATE_FORMAT(`trainings_trainings`.`date`, "%Y") = training_year
) ndt,
`trainings_inscriptions` i
INNER JOIN `trainings_trainings` t ON i.`id_training` = t.id
GROUP BY training_year;
```

The problem is I can't access training_year in my subqueries. How can I do that?

My first try was to move the subqueries in the SELECT part, but after doing so I can't use these subqueries' aliases for the cancellation_rate calculation.

**EDIT**

I have the result expected with @Jafar's query and some modifications:

```
SELECT current_year, nb_trainees, nb_canceled_trainings, nb_done_trainings, 
        (nb_canceled_trainings / (nb_canceled_trainings + nb_done_trainings)) cancellation_rate,
        (nb_trainees / nb_done_trainings) filling
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN `t`.`id_status` = 5 THEN 1 END) nb_canceled_trainings,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `t`.`id_status` IN (6, 7) THEN 1 END) nb_done_trainings, (
        SELECT COUNT(`ti`.`id`) nb_trainees
        FROM `trainings_inscriptions` `ti`
        INNER JOIN `trainings_trainings` `tt` ON `ti`.`id_training` = `tt`.`id`
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT (`tt`.`date`, "%Y") = DATE_FORMAT (`t`.`date`, "%Y")
    ) nb_trainees, DATE_FORMAT (`t`.`date`, "%Y") current_year
    FROM `trainings_trainings` `t`
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT (`t`.`date`, "%Y")
) dummy;
```

This is what I get:

```
+------+----------+----------+------+--------+---------+
| year | trainees | canceled | done | ratio  | filling |
+------+----------+----------+------+--------+---------+
| 2012 |        0 |        0 |    0 | NULL   | NULL    |
| 2013 |       58 |        0 |    2 | 0.0000 | 29.0000 |
| 2014 |        2 |        1 |    0 | 1.0000 | NULL    |
+------+----------+----------+------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? also your query is wrong..does this run for you?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. I want to know the number of cancelled trainings, done trainings and the cancellation rate by year.

The trainings_trainings table contains the date of the training and trainings_inscriptions the users inscription for a training.

So my query "works" if I remove the condition on the training date in my subqueries but the results is not the expected because it will count for all years not the "current".

Comment: check my edited answer..it would do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the alias infront of your table name and use it within the subquery itself, and if you are referencing an outer table then it would be better to select that field then join with the outer table.

---

**EDIT v2.0** changed query to get the results desired

```
    SELECT YEAR,
       TRAINEES,
       NCT,
       NDT,
       NCT / (NCT + NDT) RATIO
  FROM (  SELECT COUNT (CASE WHEN T.ID_STATUS = 5 THEN 1 END) NCT,
                 COUNT (CASE WHEN T.ID_STATUS IN (6, 7) THEN 1 END) NDT,
                 (SELECT COUNT (TI.ID) TRAINEES
                    FROM trainings_inscriptions TI
                   WHERE TI.id_training = T.ID)
                    TRAINEES,
                 DATE_FORMAT (T.date, "%Y") year
            FROM trainings_trainings t
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT (T.date, "%Y"))
```

Comment: It's almost good. NCT and NDT are false (NDT is 3 instead of 2 and NCT is 2 instead of 1).

Comment: is your join 1-to-1? whats the relation between `trainings_trainings` and `trainings_inscriptions`?

Comment: It's a one-to-many. If I launch only the NCT COUNT (or the NDT) the result is correct but the association of both corrupts results.

Comment: @DjLeChuck ok I just read your explaination ... I think this would get what you want.

Comment: Yes it's good, I was doing it, except two typo mistakes: `COUNT(i.id)` instead of `COUNT(ti.id)` and `WHERE ti.id = t.id` instead of `WHERE ti.id_training = t.id`. Thank you you make my day. :-)

Comment: Another change: `TRAINEES` must be the global number of inscriptions so I joined `INNER JOIN trainings_trainings tt ON ti.id_training = tt.id` and I added a condition `WHERE DATE_FORMAT (tt.date, "%Y") = DATE_FORMAT (t.date, "%Y")`. Anyway, thanks for all Jafar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the subqueries like this

```
SELECT COUNT(`trainings_trainings`.`id`) nb_canceled_trainings,
  DATE_FORMAT(`trainings_trainings`.`date`, "%Y") training_year
FROM  `trainings_trainings`
WHERE `trainings_trainings`.`id_status` = 5
GROUP BY training_year
```

then you can use the alias's field `training_year` in the `WHERE` section of main query.